# Should Fuses be Hot All the Time

Tags: electrical

I have a 2014 Jeep Cherokee Latitude in which I don’t have hot on the battery side of the blower motor fuse while the car is running and I’m wondering if this is normal or if this is somehow controlled by a relay or switch prior to going to the fuse box?

Comment: There could be a relay or fuse prior to that fuse - have you checked the legend of which fuses and relays are linked to which function?

Comment: Yes and I found that there is a blower motor fuse and a blower motor relay. The relay seems to be working however I don’t know how to tell for sure.

Comment: Blower motor fuse should be hot on both sides of the fuse with key on and blower turned on, if only one side then the fuse is bad.